# What is the maximum earnable gold for the Elder Elemental Eye?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-encounters

I just finished playing Season 8 of D&D Encounters, Elder Elemental Eye. I really liked the character, so I'd like to take her forward for Living Realms. But, I didn't keep very good notes on gold earned - can somebody please tell me the maximum earnable gold for the adventure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrapped playing it 3 weeks ago. If you don't save an NPC early on you can earn around 335-350 max gold per player as far as I can tell.

Comment: And if you do save them its 25 gp less per player

Answer (score -1):

I don't have that specific adventure, but if it follows the Treasure Parcel system (*Dungeon Master's Guide, p.126*) the party should have been awarded 720g by the end of level 1, 1,040g by the end of level 2, and 1,355g by the end of level 3. Assuming a party of 5 and a complete 1-3 adventure, 623g each. If you don't have specific notes, that value might be your best bet!